# Hybrid drive in ASUS K551LN laptop - only AHCI mode in SATA Mode Selection in BIOS

Tags: ssd, bios, sata, asus-laptop, hybrid-storage

I recently bought ASUS K551LN laptop with hybrid drive in it (didn't ask for it, it just happened that this model came with it). As SSD partition is only 24GB which is not enough to install OS onto it (at least Win7 that I need).  I'd like to use it for caching. For that I need to change SATA mode in BIOS from AHCI to RAID which I can't as I don't get to select any other SATA mode other than AHCI so I was wondering if anyone here had the same problem as it's driving me crazy cause currently Windows sees SSD drive as separate disk. I flashed BIOS to the latest version available (2.15.1236 and btw its American Megatrends) so I'm pretty stuck here.

Comment: It sounds like your hardware does not have a RAID controller.  What makes you think you do have one?

Comment: Well, chipset supports RTS so laptop should have a RAID controller (it's Intel HM76 Express). I really doubt ASUS would ship hybrid drive with laptop that cannot fully utilize its capabilities.

Comment: Its very possible due to it being regional product it is that the firmware is limited in some capacity. I found a thread in French that seems to indicate it should be possible, but the person indicate the option was missing, I suggest contacting Asus for assistance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already wrote to them, before I posted a question here, but it will take some time until they reply I guess...

Comment: Eh... Why would you need to change it to RAID? It's a hybrid disk.. It can be used as a standard AHCI, surely? You can let the controller manage the disk and then any software to configure what area (SSD/mechanical) is used for what... Our am I misunderstanding something?!

Comment: Can you please specify "any software"? In Intel's Rapid Storage Technology Application there's no such option...

Comment: I found an article at PC World that clearly states RAID should be configured:  http://www.pcworld.com/article/248828/how_to_setup_intel_smart_response_ssd_caching_technology.html

Comment: Note that 24GB is enough to install your OS and basic applications (at least for windows 7 x64. After that about 4GB will be left).

Answer (score 0):

OK. after a lot of research I finally found a solution thanks to Paul Berry. Ramhound, you were partially right but you cannot use any software, seems it has to be Express Cache from Disk Keeper that ASUS ships with their laptops that come with pre-installed OS. Intel RST driver has to be installed prior to installation of ExpressCache. Here's the link to blog that helped me solve the issue:

http://www.tall-paul.co.uk/2013/05/01/enabling-expresscache-on-the-asus-ux32a/#comment-4595